# Cannot write pipe character | in IntelliJ Terminal

Tags: bash, intellij-idea, terminal

Since a couple of months I cannot write any special character that uses the ALT-modifier  in my IntelliJ Terminal.

ALT+7 is usually my pipe character - which works in IntelliJ Editor.

But in the Terminal it does not work - instead the next character pushed will be inserted 7 times.
If I choose bash Terminal instead of my standard zsh it changes the prompt `bash-3.2$`  to
`(arg: 7)`  when typing ALT+7.

`bash-3.2$`

< ALT+7

`(arg: 7)`

< d

`bash-3.2$ ddddddd`

I'm pretty sure I didn't have this problem with older IntelliJ versions, but this came with an update.

I'm using IntelliJ 2021.2 on MacOSX Big Sur.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 (Ultimate Edition) 
Build #IU-212.4746.92, built on July 27, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1504.13 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.4
```

Does anyone know where this comes from and how to fix that - the Terminal is unusable like this ;-)

Comment: Check the Keymap section of preferences to see if Alt-7 has been assigned as a shortcut for something else.

Comment: That sounds like default readline behaviour: meta key plus digits repeats what follows by the number represented by the digits, see the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Arguments).

Comment: Alt-7 is unassigned in Keymap

Comment: yes - seems like to be that readline behaviour - how can I deactivate that - and why do I have this behavior only in IntelliJ and not on the regular macOS terminal or other shell programs

Comment: @zidjian : In many configurations, typing a modifier key together with a digit, repeats the next key this number of times. Historically, this comes from the _emacs_ keymappings, though in original emacs, this modifier was, as far I remember, _control_, and not _alt_. Do you see the same behaviour also in a bash shell run inside a Mac Terminal instead of  your IDE? What keyboard (i.e. which language) are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the *Use Option as Meta key* option in the settings: *Preferences | Tools | Terminal*.